# SQL to Match columns from 2 different tables using a Select statement

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 tables A & B with columns 6 columns in each table.
Table A has lesser rows than table B.

I want to write a Select Statement where if the below condition satisfies

-----A.Col1=B.Col1 and A.Col2=B.Col2 and A.Col3=B.Col3 and A.Col4=B.Col4 and A.Col5=B.Col5 and A.Col6=B.Col6-----

if all conditions are satisfied then in a new column say "Match" else "NoMatch"

How do I do that ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `exists`.  If you want a new column in `A`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from b
                          where A.Col1 = B.Col1 and A.Col2 = B.Col2 and
                                A.Col3 = B.Col3 and A.Col4 = B.Col4 and
                                A.Col5 = B.Col5 and A.Col6 = B.Col6
                         )
             then 'match' else 'nomatch'
        end) as flag
from a;
```

Note:  If you want the new column on `B`, the logic is the same but the two tables are reversed.

If any of the columns can have `NULL` values, then you need to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` statement and I am considering that you need all data from `tableB` and matching data from `tableA` as follows:

```
select b.*, a.*,
       case when A.Col1=B.Col1 and A.Col2=B.Col2 
             and A.Col3=B.Col3 and A.Col4=B.Col4 
             and A.Col5=B.Col5 and A.Col6=B.Col6
            then 'Match'  
            else 'No match'    
       end as res
  from tableB b 
  left join TableA a
    on A.Col1=B.Col1 and A.Col2=B.Col2 
   and A.Col3=B.Col3 and A.Col4=B.Col4 
   and A.Col5=B.Col5 and A.Col6=B.Col6
```